# @ManyToOne Relation with Join table (nullable = false)

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

Trying to create a `@ManyToOne` relation in a separate table between `TestEntity` and `TestAttr` getting the error response:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.test.TestEntity.testAttr; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.test.TestEntity.testAttr
```

here is the entity that has the problem:

```
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class TestEntity{

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "test_attr_test_entity", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "test_entity_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "test_attr_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
  private TestAttr testAttr;
  .
  .
  .
 }
```

And when changing to `@ManyToMany` it works without errors.

Persistence code:

```
testEntityRepository.save(testEntity)
```

Comment: Probably you are trying to persist a `TestEntity` whose `testAttr` property is `null`, but we really need a [mcve] to be sure.  Also, why are you using a join table for a many-to-one relationship?  It's *allowed*, but rarely is it good form.

Comment: Actually yes, I am trying to persist a TestEntity who doesn't have a testAttr, and the @ManyToOne relation is supposed to be optional by default. So why can't I persist a  TestEntity  with null testAttr?

Comment: could you add the entities code ?

Comment: 1. Why you want to create join table for @ManyToOne relationship. 2. If you really want to create one, then you can't persist TestEntity with null testAttr, cause you've specified it in `name = "test_attr_id", nullable = false,...`3. Maybe just write down what you want to accomplish so we shall rethink and offer some solution.

Comment: 1. I need another table because in most cases there won't be a testAttr, and I don't want a column with mostly nulls, 2. I just want to make sure that in the table "test_attr_test_entity" nulls isn't allowed.

Comment: @J.Kennsy, why does (name = "test_attr_id", nullable = false,...) implies that testAttr must not be null, as I understand it means that the column "test_attr_id" must not be null in the table "test_attr_test_entity". Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should like at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and) example. If you want to apply what's written there to your project, your entities may look like this:

---

#### TestEntity

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private TestAttr testAttr;
...
```

#### TestAttr

```
@Entity
public class TestAttr {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
...
```

Example of persisting using Spring Data repositories:

```
TestAttr attr = new TestAttr();

testAttrRepository.save(attr);

TestEntity entity1 = new TestEntity();
TestEntity entity2 = new TestEntity();

entity1.setTestAttr(attr);
entity2.setTestAttr(attr);

testEntityRepository.save(entity1);
testEntityRepository.save(entity2);
```

#### Tables

As you can see now TestEntity has ID of it's testAttr in database:

[image: tables in database]

**Note** This is one-way OneToMany relation ship. (TestEntity has reference to it's testAttr, but TestAttr doesn't have list of it's testEntities 
Behavior of repo methods you can moderate with cascade types as you want.
Hope I helped :)

Comment: Actually I need to have the relation in a separate table. And I don't know why does (name = "test_attr_id", nullable = false,...) in this context prevents me from persisting an entity of type TestEntity without testAttr.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedTaherMohamed If you have separate table for this relation and you persist TestEntity with testAttr it's gonna create row in this table with id of testEntity and id of testAttr. If you don't want to have any nulls in this table then you can't persist one entity without another.